# i have .idea in my repo in Github how do i hide it? from android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

idea folder doesn't hide in gitignore.

i have used gitignore procedure by adding the folder

"/.idea"

Answer (score 0):

In root of project add a .gitignore file with the following:

```
# IntelliJ blanket ignore
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
**/.idea/*
```

then delete .idea.